# How to change start menu location for Windows 7 Programs

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts, start-menu

I keep my start menu in Windows 7 very organized, but every time there's a program update available (Safari for example), the program recreates its shortcut icons in the default start menu location for that program (Safari, for example, recreates start menu short icons in "Start Menu\All Programs\Safari").

So, every time I update a program I have to move it's start menu icons again to keep them organized the way I like. Some programs ask where I would like the start menu icon placed, and that works fine, but for the programs that don't ask...

Is there a way to set a default start menu location for programs so that when I update, the shortcuts are placed in the folders I want them to be at? (Safari for example I keep in "Start Menu\All Programs\Web Browsers\Safari.lnk")

Comment: Wow, nobody has anything on this? Seriously?

Comment: Maybe you could make your Start Menu read-only?

Comment: I'd assume that's because just using the built-in search box is easier than navigating to menus and such.

Comment: This question was bumped by community. Since Windows 7 is a very old operative system I think this should be closed as no longer reproducible. People having new questions in Windows 7 might be better served in [retrocomputing.se].

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this works, but I just tried it:
START BUTTON, type "regedit", right-click regedit.exe in the search box and choose "Run as Administrator"
Search for key

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Folders

Scroll all the way to the bottom or search for 
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\

For each entry you want to change, hit F2 to rename and enter the correct path you want the shortcuts to be stored.

I will find out if it works the next time iTunes updates itself.

Comment: Did this work for you? I see a lot of iTunes related folders and not sure which one to change.